# Issues with some remote sites sending binary data over WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

This issue that I am having doesn't happen all the time, but for specific WCF clients I am logging the following exception:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException
>
> An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other
>   party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.
>
> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: An unsecured or
>   incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the
>   inner FaultException for the fault code and detail. --->
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error occurred when verifying
>   security for the message.     --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.SecurityRequestSessionChannel.ProcessReply(Message
>   reply, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState
>   correlationState)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.SecurityRequestSessionChannel.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)     at 
>   Proxy.ExecutionResultsUpdateService.IExecutionResultsUpdateService.SaveBinaryResults(SaveBinaryResultsRequest
>   request)     at 
>   Proxy.ExecutionResultsUpdateService.ExecutionResultsUpdateServiceClient.
>   **> Proxy.ExecutionResultsUpdateService.IExecutionResultsUpdateService.SaveBinaryResults(SaveBinaryResultsRequest
>   request)**     at 
>   LoggingExecutionResultsUpdateServiceClient.SaveBinaryResults(SaveBinaryResultsRequest
>   request)     at  ClientServices.ResultsController.Send(IEnumerable`1
>   resultsList)     at  NMA.StartAutomaticAgent()     at 
>   MainApplication.Start()

That exception is being thrown by the client.

The service code for SaveBinaryResults is:

```
[ServiceContract(Name="IExecutionResultsUpdateService")]
public interface IExecutionResultsUpdateService_v1_0_1 : IExecutionResultsUpdateService
{
    [OperationContract(Name="SaveBinaryResults")]
    void SaveSQLResults(byte[] data, string serverXml, Guid clientInstanceId, int moduleId, Guid batchIdentifier);
}

   public void SaveSQLResults(byte[] data, string serverXml, Guid clientInstanceId, int moduleId, Guid batchIdentifier)
    {
        DataSet dataSet = (DataSet)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(new MemoryStream(data));

        try
        {
            XmlDocument serverDocument = new XmlDocument();
            serverDocument.LoadXml(serverXml);

            executionResultsRepository.Save(dataSet, serverDocument);
            executionHistoryRepository.SaveModuleExecution(clientInstanceId, moduleId, true, null, batchIdentifier);
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            executionHistoryRepository.SaveModuleExecution(clientInstanceId, moduleId, false, ex.ToString(), batchIdentifier);
            throw new FaultException<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException>(ex, new FaultReason(ex.Message));
        }
    }
```

The client proxy configuration for IExecutionResultsUpdateService is:

> ```
> <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IExecutionResultsUpdateService"
>   closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
>   sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false"
>   hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
>   maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8"
>   useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
>   <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
>     maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
>   <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
>     enabled="false" />
>   <security mode="Message">
>     <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
>       realm="" />
>     <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
>       algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
>   </security>
> </binding>
> ```

The service configuration is

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" 
    name="Services.ExecutionResultsUpdateService">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration="MtomWsHttpBindingForBigArrays" 
      contract="Services.IExecutionResultsUpdateService_v1_0_1" 
      address="/ExecutionResults"/>
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding" 
      contract="Services.IExecutionResultsUpdateService_v1_0_1"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://[ipaddress]/ExecutionResultsUpdateService.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
</service>

   <binding name="MtomWsHttpBindingForBigArrays" 
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
         messageEncoding="Mtom" 
         receiveTimeout="5"              
         useDefaultWebProxy="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
             maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
             maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
             maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
             maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
    </binding>
```

A portion of the client proxy looks like this:

```
public interface IExecutionResultsUpdateService
{
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IExecutionResultsUpdateService/ReportPackageCompletion", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IExecutionResultsUpdateService/ReportPackageCompletionResponse" +
        "")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
    void ReportPackageCompletion(string clientInstanceId, int packageId);

    // CODEGEN: Parameter 'data' requires additional schema information that cannot be captured using the parameter mode. The specific attribute is 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute'.
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IExecutionResultsUpdateService/SaveBinaryResults", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IExecutionResultsUpdateService/SaveBinaryResultsResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
    Proxy.ExecutionResultsUpdateService.SaveBinaryResultsResponse SaveBinaryResults(Proxy.ExecutionResultsUpdateService.SaveBinaryResultsRequest request);
}
```

Note: The two end points was because I had to support two versions of this service.  The service with the binding "MtomWsHttpBindingForBigArrays" is the one that is cause my problems. (The other one does the same thing but accepted a DataSet as a parameter except a byte[], which I soon discovered was inefficient and bad practice.)

Does any one know if this getting rid of this exception is something withing my control?  Are there any configuration changes that I can make on either the client or service config files?

If you need anymore information from me please let me know.

Comment: how big is the data these clients sent ? Are these client in a different timezone or have some time problems ?

Comment: The data is not that big.  Couple of MB max.

Answer (score 0):

Is the error being thrown every time those clients make the call? If so, check the clock/time zone/date on the client.

Comment: There are clients all over the US.  Yes.  It is happening everytime the clients that generate that exception and they do seem in another timezone.

Comment: Just make sure that the timezone/date/time are correct for that particular client. Anything more than 5 minutes off and the call will fail. Also, if you can vnc into the client machine, try to ping the base URL of your service, to see if the machine can even get there.

Comment: The client call is definately reaching the service because there is another service call before this one that succeeds as well as the fact that the client error information is send back using another wcf client proxy.

Comment: Try disabling the message security and see if it still sends the error. Perhaps the username is wrong.

Comment: The username and password is being supplied directly in the code after it is decrypted. There is no human interaction between the client and these services. The proxies that I generated are distributed with an application and executed automatically